# Spring Boot - Kotlin - Unable to initialise a data class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm using Spring Boot along with the RabbitMQ packages and Kotlin.

I have written the following data class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class ErrorMessageModel(
        val status: String = "",
        val output: ErrorOutputKey = ErrorOutputKey(ErrorKey("", emptyList()))
)

data class ErrorOutputKey(
        val error: ErrorKey = ErrorKey( "", emptyList())
)

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class ErrorKey(
        @JsonProperty("-so-message")
        val message: String = "",
        val backtrace: List<String> = emptyList()
)
```

Along with this code to read from the queue itself is this: (note I've implemented the appropriate byte array using Jackson so no issues in that part, I've tested with other queues/data models and it works fine):

```
@RabbitListener(queues = ["\${a.error.queue}"])
    fun receivedErrorMessage(data: ErrorMessageModel) {
        //For the time being
        println(data)
    }
```

The issue I need help with is:

- I keep seeing the error: `org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [[B] to [com.models.ErrorMessageModel]`. However when I comment out the line `val output: ErrorOutputKey` in `ErrorMessageModel`, it works fine. What is it about that's causing an issue. Of course if I remove `val output: ErrorOutputKey` it works.

And as a side question, when it comes to initialising `val output: ErrorOutputKey` is the way I have done it above valid - it seems like quite cumbersome code?

Thanks,

UPDATE

The JSON I'm testing looks like this:

```
{
    "status": "TError",
    "output": {
        "error": {
            "class": "NoMethodError",
            "-so-message": "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass",
            "backtrace": [
                "errorinfo1",
                "errorinfo2"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And here;s the full stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException: Error Handler converted exception to fatal
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.handleError(ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.java:105) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeErrorHandler(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1378) [spring-rabbit-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.handleListenerException(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1631) [spring-rabbit-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1424) [spring-rabbit-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:870) [spring-rabbit-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:854) [spring-rabbit-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:78) [spring-rabbit-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1137) [spring-rabbit-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1043) [spring-rabbit-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message
Endpoint handler details:
Method [public void com.listeners.ErrorQueuesListener.receivedErrorMessage(com.models.ErrorMessageModel)]
Bean [com.listeners.ErrorQueuesListener@32347372]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:199) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:129) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1552) [spring-rabbit-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1478) [spring-rabbit-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1466) [spring-rabbit-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1461) [spring-rabbit-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1410) [spring-rabbit-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [[B] to [com.models.ErrorMessageModel] for GenericMessage [payload=byte[2560]]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.PayloadArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PayloadArgumentResolver.java:144) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:117) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:148) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:50) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:196) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Looks like the issue is around `@JsonProperty("-so-message")` - when I remove that it's behaving better.

Comment: Not sure why the above is though - i can't do `val -so-message: String = "",` so I need that `@JsonProperty`

Comment: It's quite hard to tell how to fix the issue if we don't have the complete stack trace of the exception and, most importantly, the JSON that you're trying to map to these classes. Post a complete minimal example, not involving Rabbit or even Spring, but just a hard-coded String containing the JSON document to parse, and a call to the ObjectMapper to parse that String to an ErrorMessageModel.

Comment: @JBNizet - I've added those details

Comment: So why do you use `@JsonProperty("-so-message")`, since the property is named `message` in the JSON?

Comment: Sorry - that was typo I've corrected. It does have `-so-message`

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view it looks like the rabbit listener tries to convert a byte array into an object. The mapping of messages to objects in Spring AMQP only works when the message itself has the content type of `application/json` set - see https://www.rabbitmq.com/publishers.html#message-properties.
If there isn't any content type header or there isn't a matching message converter for the given content type Spring AMQP falls back to the byte array listener.
So you basically have two choices:

1. Publish the consumed messages with content type `application/json`
2. Change the listener method in a way it takes the byte array as argument instead of the specific object and converts it by itself using the `jacksonObjectMapper()`